# Auto assign predefined env vars \ mounts to every pod (including future ones) on a cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, configmap

Problem:

I want every pod created in my cluster to hold\point the same data
e.g. let's say I want all of them to have an env vars like "OWNER=MYNAME".
there are multiple users in my cluster and I don't want them to start changing their YAMLs and manually assign OWNER:MYNAME to env.

Is there a way to have all current/future pods to be assigned automatically with a predefined value or mount a configmap so that the same information will be available in every single pod?
can this be done on the cluster level? namespace level?
I want it to be transparent to the user, meaning a user would apply whatever pod to the cluster, and the info could be available to him without even asking.

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

[Pod Preset](https://v1-19.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/podpreset/) might help you here to partially achieve what you need. Pod Preset resource allows injecting additional runtime requirements into a Pod at creation time. You use label selectors to specify the Pods to which a given PodPreset applies.

Check this to know [how pod preset works](https://v1-19.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/podpreset/#how-it-works).

- First you need to [enable pod preset in your cluster](https://v1-19.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/podpreset/#enable-pod-preset).
- You can use Pod Preset to [inject env variables or volumes](https://v1-19.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/podpreset/#use-pod-presets-to-inject-environment-variables-and-volumes) in your pod.
- You can also [inject configmap](https://v1-19.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/podpreset/#pod-spec-with-configmap-example) in your pod.
- Make use of some common label for all the pods which you want to have common config, use this common label in your pod preset resource.

Unfortunately there are [plans to remove pod presets altogether](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/93900) in coming releases, but I guess you can still use it with current releases. Although there are [other implementations similar to pod presets](https://github.com/redhat-cop/podpreset-webhook), which you can try.

Comment: thanks, could it be that pod presets have been deprecated?